# How to properly create and save for web animated slides with text on image background

Tags: text, gif, image-quality, image-format

Following on from this question PNG vs. GIF vs. JPEG vs. SVG - When best to use? regarding mr. @ChuckLeButt 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752936/4642215).

I have a situation trying to create and save for web a few picture slides merged into a gif. Each of every picture contain text layers over rich color image background. It's well known the fact that Photoshop it's best to be used for picture editing being a pixel based software not for text editing/output; On the other hand, Illustrator could be a good solution for text editing/output but not necesarily for editing pictures taking in consideration the fact that we are talking about a vector based software in this case. More than that, animated GIF's are loseless BUT indexed only. I suppose that somehow there shoud be a compromise (?!)

My quetion is, how do you approach these kind of situations, excepting the css/html/js alternatives for implementing and animating content in web design please? Thanks

Comment: (As stated in the question you link to) GIF is not the best option for any full color photographs. Unless you want animation (I know you do) PNG is probably a better option most of the time. With regards to animation, if CSS or JS animations are a viable option I would go for that.

Comment: Also, Illustrator/Photoshop doesn't really come in to it regarding file formats. You can save to any of the formats you mention from either. Use whichever software fits what you are doing.